# What is the subject in this sentence? "Bei uns zu hause spricht keiner Deutsch."

Tags: subject

I do not know if there is a subject in this sentence:

> Bei uns zu Hause spricht keiner Deutsch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a subject: *keiner*.

Comment: What is the difference between "keiner" and "niemand"?

Comment: In this sentence you could use either. _Niemand_ is a bit more formal and can generally only be used for persons, though.

Comment: @DonHolgo: so you have to use `keiner` if you want to be clear that the dog doesn't speak German either?

Comment: @TonyK: I guess so, although probably nobody would understand the sentence with _niemand_ to say that maybe the dog does. I rather wanted to point out that it's wrong to use _niemand_ when talking about balloons and saying _keiner ist rot_, for example.